# (XCode) Turning off warnings when compiling certain files?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, warnings

I use several third-party libraries in my iOS project that generate some warnings.  Is there a way I can turn off warnings on those specific files only, similar to the way you can turn off ARC on a per-file basis by adding the "-fno-objc-arc" flag to the "compile sources" area in build phases?

Comment: what kind of warnings are you trying to ignore and is it a good idea to really ignore them?

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, there's an option to set per-file compiler flags:

- In the Project Navigator pane, click on your project
- Select the target you're building with
- Choose the Build Phases tab
- Scroll down and expand the Compile Sources phase
- Locate the "Compiler Flags" column
- Set the compiler flag to -w for the file you want to suppress warnings for